# Android sdk is not available when i start android studio for the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I just installed android studio, but when I launch it, it goes to this page :
[image: Screenshot 1]

I click the "Next" button, and it comes to this screen :
[image: Screenshot 2]
I can't check Android SDK to install, and When I skip through, I get to this page :
[image: Screenshot 3]

And each time I try to start a new project, this comes up:
[image: Screenshot 4]

I searched a lot and tried every solution I could find, but nothing has worked yet.
I changed my proxy settings, reinstalled Android Studio, and created new rules in firewall settings (both inbound and outbound). I even tried to install the SDK manually but couldn't because I don't quite know how.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Reinstall Android Studio with custom customization. Install SDK with the installation of android sutdio.

Comment: I've tried it a few times and it finally worked thanks.